# How to consolidate rows in table for the given scenario?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table

```
CustId Name   Age  Gender   Business    Code
1      John   24   Male     Automobiles 1
2      Peter  30   Male     Space       3
2      Peter  30   Male     IT          null
3      Kris   48   Female   Infra       null
```

I need output as follows

```
CustId Name   Age  Gender   Business           Code
1      John   24   Male     Automobiles        1
2      Peter  30   Male     Space              3
3      Kris   48   Female   CodeNotAvailable   null
```

Peter has two businesses one with code and another without code. So, the row without code is removed.

Kris has business without code, so need to display `CodeNotAvailable` in `Business` column.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the row numbers and pick the row. By default, SQL Server orders NULL first. We need to use `order by code desc` to get the non-null value as the first row in the `ROW_NUBER()`

```sql
SELECT CustId,Name,  Age,  Gender,  Business,    Code
from
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustId ORDER BY Code desc) as rnk
FROM Table) as t
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with r as (
    select Custid, Name, Age, Gender, 
        case when code is null then 'CodeNotAvailable' else Business end as Business,
        Code
    from myTab
)
select max(CustId) CustId, Name, Age, Gender, Business, Code
from r
group by Name, Age, Gender, Business, Code
```